# Trying to use regex to match to a description in our website

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex to match to something like this:

```
<p><strong>Surrounded by the stunning mountains of Steinernes Meer in the Austrian Alps</strong></p>
```

As far as I can see, this should work:

```
<p><strong>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]<\/strong><\/p>
```

However that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I thought the bit I have in the middle should match to any number of alphanumeric characters, and the bit at the end should be the same as the first part (which works), but I've added some backslashes to escape the forward slashes?

Comment: I think you forgot a `+` after the character class.

Comment: That only matches one character. You need to add `+` or `*` (match one or more / zero or more times) to match more than one character.

Comment: Regulex is quite useful to check regex: https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

- `<p><strong>(.*)<\/strong><\/p>`
- `(.*)` - returns a matched group of all charachters in-between `<p><strong>` tags

---

```js
const regex = /<p><strong>(.*)<\/strong><\/p>/gm;
const str = `<p><strong>Surrounded by the stunning mountains of Steinernes Meer in the Austrian Alps</strong></p>`;

console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed and works! But now I'm having issues isolating the part in the middle - if I use (.*) it just copies the whole thing again but if I use the thing I was using previously it continues to return null. Am I wrong in thinking that [a-zA-Z0-9 ]* should return any alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Glad to be of any help. @Jul

Comment: apologies, pressed enter before actually having finished the comment - any chance you could help with the second question? Thanks so much anyway though!

Comment: @Jul in your regex you have to use quantifiers such as `+` or `*`, in your example, you don't have it, that's why it's returning null. Also, `regex.exec` returns an array of all matches, take that into consideration.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for clarifying. What I'm trying to do now is to match to the text part (without the <strong> bits) - I assumed (.*) would do it, but it's returning /(.*)/ for some reason

Comment: If you want to match the text without `<strong>` tags, you have to find out common patterns that your text has and then search by them :)

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `<p><strong>[\w\s]*<\/strong><\/p>`

**Explanation**:

`\w` - matches alpha-numeric characters, similar to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

`\s` - matches `space`

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/IqaLNB/3)